# Swagger annotation to get authorize button

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger to document my java REST API.
`X-Auth-Token` should be send in a header of each api (except one).
I would like to have the button like in the pet store V2 of authorize.
Can be found here: http://petstore.swagger.io/

I understood that it is defined in the jason\yaml file that generated is by swagger. 
To be exact it is done in yaml like this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  petstore_auth:
    type: "oauth2"
    authorizationUrl: "http://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/dialog"
    flow: "implicit"
    scopes:
      write:pets: "modify pets in your account"
      read:pets: "read your pets"
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "api_key"
    in: "header"
```

All my swagger documentation I did with annotations. But I couldn't find the annotation that does this button.
Can you help me to find this annotation please?

Thank you!

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: By adding field in @SwaggerDefinition. I'll update the answer on Sunday

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(apiKeyAuthDefinitions = {@ApiKeyAuthDefinition(key = "X-Auth-Token",
    in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER, name = "X-Auth-Token")}))
```

Then I got an "Authorized" button in the Swagger-UI. 
I checked what it did - it called a method `self.api.clientAuthorizations.add`
when `self = window.swaggerUi;'.

So finally I did an automate authorization by calling to an ajax call getting back a token and calling this method:

```
self.api.clientAuthorizations.add('X-Auth-Token',
                  new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("X-Auth-Token", Object.keys(response).map(function (key)
                  { return response[key]}), "header"));
```

Comment: @tisbar Helped?

Comment: Not sure about @tisbar, but you definitely helped me. Saved me days of frustration, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the Authorize button, you will need this:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

Then for each endpoint that requires this auth, you will need to add something like this:

```
 security:
   - bearerAuth: []
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swagger REST API operation annotation @ApiOperation also takes the following attribute: authorizations. This attribute can be set to {@Authorization(value = "AuthName")}